# Find part of string and mark as bold

Tags: jquery, regex, string, replace

I have a DIV-container which is getting filled with free text from a db.

I need to highlight that part of each row in bold, where we have text followed by a colon (:).

```
<b>1. Line:</b> Lorem ipsum
<b>Another line:</b> dolor sit
```

I guess I have to identify all line breaks inside the free text first (could be <br>, \n, \r\n, CRLF ....) and then do some kind of replace?

Any ideas how to solve this?

My sample and how it should look like here ->
https://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/oakmvx1o/4/

Comment: wow... I don't  know exactly HOW but it works as hoped! Thank you Wiktor!

Comment: Maybe someone will come up with a DOM based approach, I will refrain from posting for the time being.

Comment: hmm, funny, it works in your sample, but not in my project. I get a Syntax error on the map params (on the ">" of x => x.replace)

Comment: ES5? Try [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0vLduhLu/1/)?

Comment: yeah, that was the problem! thx for having a look again!
Just one Thing: the line "Here is nothing to see" should not be displayed bold. Only that parts of a line, that are followed by a :

Comment: For a non-regex rather css solution (as Wiktor) see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text_background). You could create a css rule like `div b { background-color: yellow;  }`. This would highlight, in yellow, all bold words that are children of a div (you could specify a specific div if you want instead of applying it to all divs in your html).

Comment: ah, I fixed the last Problem regarding the parts that should not be bold.
if (x.indexOf(':') != -1) {
       return x.replace(/^[^:]+/, '<b>$&</b>');
} else {
       return x;
}
should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a solution that has 2 steps:

- split the string into an array of lines with `/<br\s*\/?>|[\r\n]+/` regex (all kinds of `<br>` and newline sequences, removing empty lines)
- enclose the start of each line up to the first `:` with a `<b>` tag with `.replace(/^[^:]+:/, '<b>$&</b>')`.

Here is a demo:

```js
$("#container").html('1. Line: Lorem ipsum<br>Another line: dolor sit<br>Here is nothing to see<br><br>Last new line: amed');
var lines = $("#container").html().split(/<br\s*\/?>|[\r\n]+/).map(function(x) { return x.replace(/^[^:]+:/, '<b>$&</b>'); });
$("#container").html(lines.join("<br/>"));
```

```css
#container { margin-bottom: 30px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This is how it looks now:<br/><hr/>
<div id="container2">
  1. Line: Lorem ipsum<br>Another line: dolor sit<br>Here is nothing to see<br><br>Last new line: amed
</div>
<hr/>
This is a new string:<br/><hr/>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: I like - thank you very much for your Support! Very helpful!!

Comment: If you are puzzled by `&$` - it is a backreference to the whole text matched with a regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow is a not a regex solution, but a css one.

Changed your fiddle, Take a look. Just followed the css rule approach mentioned above in a commentary.

https://jsfiddle.net/oakmvx1o/5/

The css rule I added: `#container2 b { background-color: yellow; }`

[image]

Comment: sorry, this is not what I'm looking for. I need to know how to get the <b> (it can be a <span class="bold"> as well) dynamically into the text. The second sample Container in my fiddle just shows illustrates what it should look like at the end.